# Unreachable code ; i dont understand why it is unreachable

Tags: java, eclipse, unreachable-code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("time to pick a name! type in your desired option");
        System.out.println("1: Harry");
        System.out.println("2: Billybob");
        System.out.println("3: Chuckle brother number 2");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        byte input = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());

        switch (input) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You have selected Harry");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You have selected Billybob");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You have selected Chuckle Brother number 2");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            break;
        }
        System.out
                .println("time to head off. select which path you want to      take");
        System.out.println("1: the path heading north towards Winterfell");
        System.out.println("2: the path heading south, towards the red keep");
        System.out
                .println("3: the path heading East, towards the Moat Caillin");

        byte input2 = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());

        switch (input2) {
        case 1:
            System.out
                    .println("you start for winterfell. the snows start strong on your way, and you die of exposure. Game Over");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out
                    .println("you arrive at the red keep. you are attacked and you lose your money. you are now a beggar in fleebottom");
            System.out
                    .println("A magician offers you a position as his assistant. select which option you take");
            System.out.println("1: accept the magicians offer.");
            System.out.println("2: kindly decline the magicians offer.");
            System.out
                    .println("3: kill the magician and take his possessions.");
            byte input3 = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());
            switch (input3) {
            case 1:
                System.out
                        .println("the magician takes you to his home, and kills you.   Game over.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out
                        .println("the magician is angry, he strikes you, and you die of an infected wound. Game over");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out
                        .println("the magician has many expensive potions. You use these to get you into a position within the red keep");
                System.out
                        .println("King Tommen asks you to become a member of the small council. he lets you select your position.. select which option you take");
                System.out.println("1: become the master of ships.");
                System.out.println("2: become the master of coin.");
                System.out.println("3: become the master of whispers.");
                byte input5 = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());

                switch (input5) {
                case 1:
                    System.out
                            .println("a storm hits a year later and you lose all of the capitals ships. you are dismissed of your position..");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out
                            .println("the capital has no money. the iron bank looks to you for their debt that is owed. you are murdered. Game over!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out
                            .println("you find out secrets of highborn lords. you are a trusted acquaintance to the king.");
                    System.out
                            .println("the king is dying. he has no sons. he asks you who he should declare as the next king");
                    System.out.println("1: you should declare myself");
                    System.out.println("2: you should declare your uncle.");
                    System.out
                            .println("3: you should deide for yourself my king.");
                    byte input4 = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());

                    switch (input4) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out
                                .println("the lord insults you at dinner. you lose your temper and walk out. the lord has you killed. Game over.");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out
                                .println("the lord accepts your decline. he offers you gold to reconsider, as he has a proposition for you.");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out
                                .println("you kill the lord, and take Moat Caillin. you marry the daughter of a highborn.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("invalid input");
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid input");

            }

            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalid input");

            break;

        case 3: {
            System.out
                    .println("You head towards Moat Caillin. the journey is swift and you are greeted by the Lord of Moat Caillin");
            System.out
                    .println("The Lord of Moat Caillin offers your his company for dinner. type in your desired option");
            System.out.println("1: accept the lords offer.");
            System.out.println("2: kindly decline the lords offer.");
            System.out.println("3: kill the lord and take his possessions.");
            byte input4 = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());

            switch (input4) {
            case 1:
                System.out
                        .println("the lord insults you at dinner. you lose your temper and walk out. the lord has you killed. Game over.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out
                        .println("the lord accepts your decline. he offers you gold to reconsider, as he has a proposition for you.");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out
                        .println("you kill the lord, and take Moat Caillin. you marry the daughter of a highborn.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid input");
            }

            break;
            Default: System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

"when it runs it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unreachable code

```
at start.main(start.java:143)"
```

i seriously cannot find how it is unreachbale, ive checked braces and all sorts, any help or tips would be appreciated

Comment: small advice use ctrl+shift+f to format your code if you use eclipse

Comment: Indent better your code. You will discover the problem in a easier manner.

Comment: When you find yourself using multiple switch statements like this, you might consider researching and using the State design pattern. It might make your code a lot easier to read and improve.

Comment: If you Indent  your code you will find out the problem by your self I bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, analyse your code,
Have a look at block

```
case 3: {
        System.out
                .println("You head towards Moat Caillin. the journey is swift and you are greeted by the Lord of Moat Caillin");
        System.out
                .println("The Lord of Moat Caillin offers your his company for dinner. type in your desired option");
        System.out.println("1: accept the lords offer.");
        System.out.println("2: kindly decline the lords offer.");
        System.out.println("3: kill the lord and take his possessions.");
        byte input4 = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());

        switch (input4) {
        case 1:
            System.out
                    .println("the lord insults you at dinner. you lose your temper and walk out. the lord has you killed. Game over.");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out
                    .println("the lord accepts your decline. he offers you gold to reconsider, as he has a proposition for you.");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out
                    .println("you kill the lord, and take Moat Caillin. you marry the daughter of a highborn.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalid input");
        }

        break;
    Default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        break;
    }
```

Let's analyse this block, what you have, is bunch of print statements, then switch block, and break after that. break cause tou to exit from this case statement, hence code after `Default` label is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned the 'Default' label after break statement, thats the problem

```
case 3: {
        System.out
                .println("You head towards Moat Caillin. the journey is swift and you are greeted by the Lord of Moat Caillin");
        System.out
                .println("The Lord of Moat Caillin offers your his company for dinner. type in your desired option");
        System.out.println("1: accept the lords offer.");
        System.out.println("2: kindly decline the lords offer.");
        System.out.println("3: kill the lord and take his possessions.");
        byte input4 = Byte.parseByte(reader.nextLine());

        switch (input4) {
        case 1:
            System.out
                    .println("the lord insults you at dinner. you lose your temper and walk out. the lord has you killed. Game over.");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out
                    .println("the lord accepts your decline. he offers you gold to reconsider, as he has a proposition for you.");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out
                    .println("you kill the lord, and take Moat Caillin. you marry the daughter of a highborn.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalid input");
        }

        break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        break;
    }
```

observe the last 3 statements, dont you observe something fishy there?

break; statement will take the control out of case statement, and the default will never get a chance to execute